# servlet basic object in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

`HttpServletRequest` basic object in jsp.
  which one prefer to using?

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(myObjectId, myObject);
request.setAttribute("myObjectId", myObjectId);
```

using implementing of this two statement in same place session?

Comment: Its depend on your requirement. If you want to keep the data for whole session you should use first otherwise you can use second approach.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want. In the first case myObject will have session scope (it will be available for the lifetime of the session). In the second it will have request scope (it will be available for the lifetime of the request).

There is also application scope.

I'd recommend reading section JSP.1.8.2 of the JSP specification for more details.

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Both statement serves different purpose.

First method is divided into two parts.

First one is `request.getSession()`

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the
>   request does not have a session, creates one.

Then `setAttribute("myObjectId", myObject);` to the session object. The values stored in this scope will persist through out current session. 
Read More on [session.setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

The second one `request.setAttribute("myObjectId", myObject)` method --

> Stores an attribute in this request. Attributes are reset between
>   requests. This method is most often used in conjunction with
>   `RequestDispatcher`.

Read More on [request.setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)